# Crawl Errors in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I have a selection of crawl errors in my Google Webmaster tools for links that no longer exist on my site. These are a result of an old hack, where a pharmacy hack linked to PDFs. These have all been removed months ago, but external sites are still linking to these pages, which are then causing crawl errors. 
Is there a way to alert Google that these links are fake/spam?

Comment: Not sure why this would be causing crawl errors. What errors are you seeing? Are you returning a 404 for those requests?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special page where google allows reporting of various spam pages, you should check this:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en&pli=1